Direct product of pure monomorphisms is pure?
I know that any direct sum of pure exact sequences is pure. More generally, the direct limit of any direct system of pure short exact sequences is pure exact. Now, let we have pure submodules and monomorphisms $0\rightarrow A_i\rightarrow B_i$, i.e. $A_i$ is a pure submodule of $B_i$ for each $i$ in an index set $I$. Is it always true that we can take direct product from these monomorphisms to get the conclusion that $\prod_{j\in J}A_i$ is a pure submodule of $\prod_{j\in J}B_i$ for each $i$? Here, $J$ is an arbitrary index set. Thanks for any suggestion or help.

It is true.
Recall that $A \subseteq B$ is a pure submodule over $R$ iff for all matrices $(r_{ij})_{1 \leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq m}$ over $R$ and all systems of equations $\sum_{j=1}^{m} r_{ij} b_j = a_i$ where $a_1,\dotsc,a_n \in A$ and $b_1,\dotsc,b_m \in B$, there are $a'_1,\dotsc,a'_m \in A$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{m} r_{ij} a'_j = a_i$.
Assume that $A = \prod_s A_s$ and $B = \prod_s B_s$ are direct products and that each $A_s \subseteq B_s$ is pure. I claim that $A \subseteq B$ is pure.
Take a matrix $(r_{ij})_{1 \leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq m}$ over $R$ and elements $a_1,\dotsc,a_n \in A$ and $b_1,\dotsc,b_m \in B$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{m} r_{ij} b_j = a_i$. Let $s \in S$. Then $\sum_{j=1}^{m} r_{ij} (b_j)_s = (a_i)_s$ holds in $B_s$. Since $A_s \subseteq B_s$ is pure, there are elements $a'_{1s},\dotsc,a'_{ms} \in A_s$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{m} r_{ij} a'_{js} = (a_i)_s$. We define $a'_j \in A$ by $(a'_j)_s := a_{js}$ for all $s \in S$. Then we get $\sum_{j=1}^{m} r_{ij} a'_j = a_i$ in the product, and we are done.
We can also phrase the proof in a more abstract way. Notice that $A \to B$ is pure when for every commutative diagram
$\begin{array}{ccc} R^n & \rightarrow & A \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ R^m & \rightarrow & B \end{array}$
there is a filler $R^m \to A$ such that the triangle
$\begin{array}{ccc} R^n & \rightarrow & A \\ \downarrow & \nearrow & \\ R^m & & \end{array}$
commutes. From this it is quite clearly that the class of such morphisms $A \to B$ is closed under all products, simply by using the universal property of a product. (They are not necessarily closed under limits, since the lack of uniqueness of fillers makes it impossible to verify the compatibility relations.) See pure subobjects for a generalization.
